Receiving not a function error while compiling localhost
I recently inherited a Docusaurus project that hasn't been updated in multiple months. I attempted to compile the project in my localhost and got the following error:
ERROR
(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.startTransition) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.startTransition) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/client/clientEntry.js:19:1203)
ERROR
(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.startTransition) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.startTransition) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/client/clientEntry.js:19:1203)

I looked through clientEntry.js, but didn't see any immediate solve. However, I'm quite new to Docusaurus in general, so perhaps the solution is simple. I've attached the clientEntry.js file as well for reference:
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
import React, { startTransition } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { BrowserRouter, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import siteConfig from '@generated/docusaurus.config';
import ExecutionEnvironment from './exports/ExecutionEnvironment';
import App from './App';
import preload from './preload';
import docusaurus from './docusaurus';
function Router({ children }) {
    return siteConfig.future.experimental_router === 'hash' ? (<HashRouter>{children}</HashRouter>) : (<BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>);
}
const hydrate = Boolean(process.env.HYDRATE_CLIENT_ENTRY);
// Client-side render (e.g: running in browser) to become single-page
// application (SPA).
if (ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM) {
    window.docusaurus = docusaurus;
    const container = document.getElementById('__docusaurus');
    const app = (<HelmetProvider>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </HelmetProvider>);
    const onRecoverableError = (error, errorInfo) => {
        console.error('Docusaurus React Root onRecoverableError:', error, errorInfo);
    };
    const renderApp = () => {
        if (window.docusaurusRoot) {
            window.docusaurusRoot.render(app);
            return;
        }
        if (hydrate) {
            window.docusaurusRoot = ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(container, app, {
                onRecoverableError,
            });
        }
        else {
            const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container, { onRecoverableError });
            root.render(app);
            window.docusaurusRoot = root;
        }
    };
    preload(window.location.pathname).then(() => {
        startTransition(renderApp);
    });
    // Webpack Hot Module Replacement API
    if (module.hot) {
        // Self-accepting method/ trick
        // (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/100#issuecomment-290911036)
        module.hot.accept();
    }
}

Any advice to resolve this would be appreciated!

what is react and docusaurus version in your package.json?
